# Wordpress - I can't display the title of a relationship field's selected item in Twig/Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I a new to Twig/Timber. I have a single post that has an ACF relationship field that allows you to choose from a particular post type (call it "training"). Say I have a post in training called "Aerobics", and that's the one I choose in the relationship field. On the page, I want to display the title and date of Aerobics.

In Timber, I have defined that as

```
$context['related_training'] = get_field('related_pd_interactive_training');
```

what I don't know is how to display it. Both of these return true, but when I try to display the title of the item in the Relationship Field, it get nothing

```
{% for trainings in post.meta('related_pd_interactive_training') %}
   {{ WHAT DO I DO HERE }}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% if post.related_pd_interactive_training %}
   {{ OR HERE }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You assigned the field to `related_training` so you should use that. Try `{{ dump(related_training) }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `get_field()` directly, it will work for singular templates, but it wouldn’t work in archive templates, because you don’t pass the post ID.

```php
$context['related_training'] = get_field( 'related_pd_interactive_training' );
```

To make it work the Timber way, you would do it the following way:

```php
$context = Timber::get_context();

$context['post'] = Timber::get_post();
```

You can then make use of a post’s `meta()` function:

```
{% for training in post.meta('related_pd_interactive_training') %}
    {{ dump(training) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now, training is probably only a post ID, depending on what you defined as a return value in your ACF field. To turn `training` into a Timber post where you can access the title and the date, you have multiple options:

### 1. Prepare it in PHP

To prepare your data in PHP, you could use `array_map` to loop over the post IDs saved in `related_pd_interactive_training` and turn them into Timber posts by calling `new Timber\Post()`.

```php
$context = Timber::get_context();
$post    = Timber::get_post();

$context['trainings'] = array_map( function( $training ) {
    return new Timber\Post( $training );
}, $post->meta( 'related_pd_interactive_training' ) );
```

To go one step further here, you could put that function into a new method by [Extending Timber](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/).

### 2. Use Post() in Twig

A shorter way to do this would be to use `Post()` in Twig, which turns a post ID *or* an array of of post IDs that you pass to Timber posts.

```
{% for training in Post(post.meta('related_pd_interactive_training')) %}
    {{ training.title }}
    {{ training.date }}
{% endfor %}
```